# Looking for a cleaner/better way than shown to confirm deletion of a row

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and not that great with Javascript/jQuery.

My end goal is to provide a Delete link to the user to delete a row from a table. I want to do it as a POST operation rather than a GET as this, as I understand, POST is best practice. I wanted to add a confirm dialog before deleting but I didn't want to use the ugly javascript confirm dialog box and I was having problems with the form submitting without waiting for the jQuery dialog box to be answered. So, I turned the submit button into a regular button and added an onclick event which calls a ConfirmDelete javascript method in which I display a custom jQuery confirmation dialog. If answered in the affirmative, I find the form by ID using the keys of the record that the user wants to delete (keys = vendor Id and Effective Date). Once ethe form is found, I use Javascript to submit the form.

```
-------------------
  public static class DateTimeExtensions
    {

        public static long ToLong(this DateTime value)
        {            
            return long.Parse(value.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
        }         
    }
---------------------------------------

@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "StateAssessment", new
{
    vendorId = Model.VendorId,
    effectiveDate = Model.EffectiveDate
},
FormMethod.Post,
new { @id = "Form_" + Model.VendorId + "_" + @Model.EffectiveDate.ToLong() }
))
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.VendorId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.EffectiveDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.LastTimeStamp)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit",
    new
    {
        vendorId = Model.VendorId,
        effectiveDate = Model.EffectiveDate
    })

            <input value="Delete" class="btn btn-link" onclick="@string.Format("ConfirmDelete('{0}','{1}')", Model.VendorId, Model.EffectiveDate.ToLong())"  />
        </td>
    </tr>
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    function ConfirmDelete(vendorId, effectiveDate) {

        var $myDialog = $('<div></div>')
            .html('Are you sure that you want to delete this State Assessment?')
            .dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: 'Delete Confirmation',
                    buttons: {
                        "OK": function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                            var form = $("#Form_" + vendorId + "_" + effectiveDate);
                            form.submit();
                            return true;
                        },
                        "Cancel": function () 
                        {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
            });

        $myDialog.dialog('open');
    }    
</script>
```

As you see, the ID of the form is constructed of the literal "Form_" concatenated with the vendor ID and EffectiveDate keys, where the EffectievDate value was normalized into a value that could be used in an ID.

This all worked, but man, it looks ugly to me and very long winded, especially when I think how easy this could be done in WinForms in a no more than few lines of code. I am looking for a better way. I'm thinking this code has noob written all over it and I'd like to denoob it.

Comment: Make the javascript code more generic. Which will accept as a parameters: title, text and `function` as a confirmation action parameter.

Comment: If I used a JavaScript dialog, the firm submission would be blocked until the dialog was confirmed and I wouldn't have to do this contrived process of a setting a unique I'd on the form. That's what I'd really like to improve. Then, I can make the dialog more generic as suggested.

Comment: Why don't you just use a class that is generic enough to point to a form? Then you can do var `form = $('yourClassName'); form.submit()`, or maybe your generic dialog box will accept the form name as a parameter?